# How to solve "has no method 'push'" error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

using the following code

```
$.getJSON('services/getCharts.php', function(json) {
    var $line1 = [];
    $.each(json.posts, function() {
        $line1 = $line1.push([this.post.rectime,this.post.actual_value]);
    });
...
});
```

with JQuery gives me the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object 1 has no method 'push'

Could anyone help me finding what is wrong?
Thanks a lot

Comment: [MDN `.push()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) *"Mutates an array by appending the given elements and returning the new length of the array."*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace

```
    $line1 = $line1.push([this.post.rectime,this.post.actual_value]);
```

with

```
    $line1.push([this.post.rectime,this.post.actual_value]);
```

[push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) changes the receiver array and returns the new length.

You get this precise error message because the length (`1`) is promoted as a `Number` when you try to call the `push` method on it.

Answer (score 4):

The [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) method returns the new length of the array, not a new array and it modifies the array it is being called upon:

```
$.each(json.posts, function() {
    $line1.push([this.post.rectime,this.post.actual_value]);
});
```

Comment: In fact it **does** return something. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

here's a really tight syntax:

```
  return Array.reduce(things, function(total, thing) {
    return total.concat([thing]);
  }, [])
```

This:

```
return total.concat([result])
```

Is similar in effects to this:

```
total.push(result);
return total;
```